# How to get rid of the Visual Studio error because it doesn't recognise the new C# 12 syntax for collection expressions?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core, c#-8.0

I have created a new project in dotnet 8 / C#12. Some of the new C#12 features are well recognised by Visual studio, for example I can do this without any errors:

```
public class MyClass(string parameter) {...}
```

while it does not work in another project in dotnet 7 (so far so good).

The problem is: when I use the new syntax to create arrays/lists:

```
int[] a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
```

the IDE doesn't recognise the syntax at all. I can compile my code correctly and run it without any errors. The error is displayed only in the IDE, it doesn't actually exist when I run the project.

Visual Studio behaves as if it were only partially aware of the new features in C#12

How can I correct this problem, if possible without reinstalling Visual Studio? Thanks

Comment: which version of visual studio are you using, and have you checked for updates? (in my version, "Help" => "Check for Updates")

Comment: Are you using Resharper? That hasn't been updated to recognise the new C# 12 features yet.

Comment: I am using the latest version of Visual Studio (17.8.1) and Resharper (JetBrains ReSharper 2023.2.3 / Build 232.0.20231101.132807 built on 2023-11-01). I think I'm going to reinstall everything, even though it's really annoying :/

Comment: That version of Resharper doesn't support the new collection initialiser yet. If you disable Resharper, do you still see the problem?

Comment: Indeed, I don't have the error when I disable ReSharper. @PanagiotisKanavos Are you sure you don't have this error with ReSharper ? Which version do you use ?

Comment: Have you tried installing [EAP version of ReSharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/nextversion/)? Rider EAP seems to support this syntax and they should have the same language engine.

Comment: Yes, I don't have the error with the EAP version of ReSharper. I will use it until the release of Resharper 2023.3

Comment: @AoooR added as an answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently ReSharper does not fully support .NET 8 SDK - see the [.NET SDK support in JetBrains Rider](https://rider-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/13244959138834) doc. Current EAP version ([Which is EAP 8 ATM](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/nextversion/)) seems to have this issue fixed so install it.

Answer (score 1):

According to [What's new in C# 12](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-12), Visual Studio 2022 support for C#12 is updated gradually, and it is recommended that you update it to the latest version.

The newest version of Visual Studio 2022 is [version 17.8.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2022/release-notes#visual-studio-2022-version-178-releases) which is released on Nov 21st, 2023, please try update your visual studio in Visual Studio Installer.

Comment: If the OP can use primary constructors then they must be using at least 17.8.0, which should also support the new list syntax.

Comment: I am using the latest version of Visual Studio (17.8.1)

Comment: According to [Primary Constructors – Using C# 12 in Rider and ReSharper](https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2023/11/23/primary-constructors-using-csharp-12-in-rider-and-resharper/), it currently only supports C# 12 on EAP(Early Access Program) version.

Comment: May I know if you have got any chance to check my reply? You could try ReSharper EAP version which support c#12.