# Resharper takes error on Collection expressions feature of C# 12

Tags: c#, resharper, visual-studio-2022, .net-8.0, c#-12.0

A good C# 12 feature is [collection expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-12#collection-expressions).

Resharper take error on this syntax

```
public List<Model> ListModels { get; set; } = []; // ERROR
```

I used the following option into Visual Studio 2022 to enable C# 12 on project:
[image: Edit Project Item Properties]
[image: C# 12 On Visual Studio Project]

I also added the following line to project file:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
        <LangVersion>latest</LangVersion> <!-- The Line -->
    </PropertyGroup>
.
.
.
</Project>
```

Is there an options to enable this feature in Resharper 2023.2.*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get rid of the Visual Studio error because it doesn't recognise the new C# 12 syntax for collection expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77542631/how-to-get-rid-of-the-visual-studio-error-because-it-doesnt-recognise-the-new-c)

Answer (score 4):

It's a pity but JetBrains has been late with new .NET/C# versions support for at least several last releases and this one is not exception in this trend. Currently Rider/ReSharper does not fully support .NET 8 SDK - check out the [.NET SDK support in JetBrains Rider](https://rider-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/13244959138834) doc.

You can try installing current EAP version ([Which is EAP 8 ATM](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/nextversion/)) of the tool which seems to have this issue fixed.

Note that either way it should not prevent the application from actually building (at least in Rider, tough false negative intellisense is not fun, yes).

See also - [Primary Constructors – Using C# 12 in Rider and ReSharper](https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2023/11/23/primary-constructors-using-csharp-12-in-rider-and-resharper/) which seems to use EAP versions of the tools.

P.S.

Make sure that you have latest version of VS for ReSharper case.