# VS22 does not know C# 12 features

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, c#-12.0

If I use C# 12 features in Visual Studio 22, it is marked as error in the code, but there is no error shown in the error list (see screenshot).

I use VS22 17.8.2, I installed .NET 8

[image: Screenshot VS22]

Comment: Visual Studio does know. You're using Resharper, which doesn't

Comment: The screenshot shows there are no errors at all, neither Build nor Intellisense errors.

Comment: Are you targeting .NET 8 in your project? Have you overridden the `LangVersion` property in your project?

Comment: Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77549728/2501279) answer.